# Django tastypie use external resource only for filtering and exclude from API response

Tags: django, tastypie

Using following resource class I am creating the API to list down all the favorite merchants for given user.

```
class FavouriteMerchantResource(ModelResource):                                                       
    '''Fetch All favourite merchants associated with given user'''                                    

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', null=True, full=True)           
    merchant = fields.ForeignKey(MerchantResource, 'merchant', null=True, full=True)                  

    class Meta:                                                                                       
        queryset = FavouriteMerchant.objects.all()                                                    
        resource_name = 'fm'                                                                          
        include_resource_uri = False                                                                  
        allowed_methods = ['get']                                                                     
        filtering = {                                                                                 
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS                                                            
        }
```

Now I want to exclude the User details from the API response but want to use username (from User table) field to filter the result.

FYI I have tried adding following exclude fields but its still resulting the user details in response :

```
excludes = ['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `dehydrate` function and remove the user from the bundle.

something like:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    del bundle.data['user']
    return bundle
```